# Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'ObjectCollection'

Tags: vb.net, arguments, expression

I am new to VB and am trying to divide the contents of two list boxes. However every time I try it is coming up with errors such as; Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'ObjectCollection'. I have been changing around the code but have not since had any luck. I would be very appreciative to any help, thanks!

```
    Dim pSmokers As Short
    pSmokers = (Val(lstSmoker.Items)) / (Val(lstTotal.Items)) * 100
    lstTotal.Items.Add(pSmokers)
```

Comment: what type is lstSmoker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `lstSmoker` is `listBox`, you are not using it properly. This will not work

```
Val(lstSmoker.Items)
```

You need to do something like this

```
Short.Parse(lstSmoker.Items(0)) ' Where "0" is index of your item in listbox
```

Again, this is assuming your item in list control is string. So your code will looke like this:

```
pSmokers = Short.Parse(lstSmoker.Items(0)) / Short.Parse(lstTotal.Items(0)) * 100
```

Unfortunately I don't know how you keep data in your list. May be you want to have count of items in the list calculated rather than data. Then do this

```
pSmokers = lstSmoker.Items.Count / lstTotal.Items.Count * 100
```

**!!!** But now you running into problem that if `pSmokers` is short, you having a division here. Means, you will get decimal number. So, you need to change the data type of `pSmokers`

You also may run into division by "0" issue if there are no smokers. To prevent it do

```
If lstTotal.Items.Count > 0 Then
    Dim pSmokers as Decimal = lstSmoker.Items.Count / lstTotal.Items.Count * 100
    txtTotal.text= pSmokers.ToString("G")
End If
```

Comment: I've changed my code to the one that you have said, its now allowing me to try and calculate it but every time its returning 100, currently the data type is short.

Comment: @IrnBru Unfortunately I don't know how you keep data in your list. May be you want to have count of items in the list calculated rather than data. Than change `lstSmoker.Items(0)` to `lstSmoker.Items.Count`. Please see my edit